# Method of Characteristics question - uniqueness of solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm currently studying a course in PDEs and I'm trying to understand the theory fully.

I had a quite basic question: I'm trying to understand why when the base characteristics and the projection of the boundary curve (onto the (x,y) plane) coincide, is it the case that we do not have a unique solution to the PDE in question?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'base characteristics' and 'projection of the boundary curve'? Do you mean when the characteristics and the given data coincide?

Comment: @mattos Sorry for my delayed response, yeah this is what I am talking about